# AMSrefs: how to cite a paper in a conference published as a book

Tags: books, amsrefs

Using AMSrefs, I am trying to create an entry for a paper in a conference proceeding that was published as a book.  Specifically, the data for the paper is

```
    label = {Sch\"ut1976},
    author = {Sch\"utzenberger, M.-P.},
    title = {La correspondance de Robinson [Robinson's correspondence]},
```

the data for the conference is

```
        title = {Combinatoire et Repr\'esentation du Groupe
        Sym\'etrique [Combinatorics and representation of the symmetric group]},
        address = {Strasbourg},
        date = {1976},
```

and the data for the book is

```
    publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
    series = {Lecture Notes in Math.},
    volume = {579},
```

but I haven't found the right combination of which field goes where to get all of the information to show in the bibliography entry.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  The package documentation (`texdoc amsrdoc`) seems to have a relevant example, starting near the end of page 13, starting with "conference".

Answer (score 1):

Ah, thanks! Specifically, in ams.org/arc/tex/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf:

```
\bib{Burkholder1986a}{article}{
    author={Burkholder, Donald L.},
    title={Martingales and Fourier analysis in Banach spaces},
    conference={
        title={C.I.M.E. Lectures},
        address={Varenna, Italy},
        date={1985}
    },
    book={
        series={Lecture Notes in Math.},
        volume={1206},
        publisher={Springer-Verlag},
        address={Berlin and New York},
        date={1986},
    },
    pages={61--108},
    review={\MR{0864712}}
}
```

The core of it being that "conference" and "book" can be used together.